# Nothing Appearing When I try To Click on A Tab Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click on the STATS tab after clicking an English Premier League match on Flashscore.com However, nothing is happening and I am getting a TimeoutException. Here is my code:

May I please know what I may be doing wrong.

```
stats = {}
    stats_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tabs__group .tabs__tab[href="#/match-summary/match-statistics"]')))
stats_tab.click()
```

Comment: Please add more details so that others can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example